# Nav Bar falls below logo while browser resizing on bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The top right fixed nav bar for bootstrap come below the logo when resizing the screen resolution. I uploaded the image on https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5bDD

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="border:0; border-radius:0;">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding:2px;" href="index.php"><img src="img/searchimage.png" width="51" height="45" /> </a>
                </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php" style="padding:10px 8px 12px 8px;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="aboutus.php">AboutUs</a>
                        </li>
...
...
...
              </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
```

Please let me know how to solve this...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use media queries to specify a smaller font-size when the screen is smaller. Something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 900px)    {
    .navbar-inverse li a   {
        fonts size: 10px;
    }
}
```

The 900px and 10px are for example purposes so you will have to check out which width and font-size will fix the layout problem.

Also, remove the inline-style padding for your list-item as that is not necessary for aligning the links